# Saving JPEG screenshot as a BYTE buffer in C

Tags: c, gdi+, byte

In one of my previous questions I asked how to take a screenshot and save it as JPEG without the use of GDI+ due to the constrains of having to use only C.
At the end I answered the question myself with the help of of some of the comments there. 
Using a very terse C version of GDI+ (loaded at runtime) i can take a screenshot and save it as a JPEG to a file.
Now, how would I save that same screenshot not to a file but to a buffer? an unsigned char* buffer?
here's the code that needs to be converted.

```
int SaveJpeg(HBITMAP hBmp, LPCWSTR lpszFilename, ULONG uQuality)
{
    ULONG *pBitmap = NULL;
    CLSID imageCLSID;
    EncoderParameters encoderParams;
    int iRes = 0;

    typedef Status (WINAPI *pGdipCreateBitmapFromHBITMAP)(HBITMAP, HPALETTE, ULONG**);
    pGdipCreateBitmapFromHBITMAP lGdipCreateBitmapFromHBITMAP;

    typedef Status (WINAPI *pGdipSaveImageToFile)(ULONG *, const WCHAR*, const CLSID*, const EncoderParameters*);
    pGdipSaveImageToFile lGdipSaveImageToFile;

    // load GdipCreateBitmapFromHBITMAP
    lGdipCreateBitmapFromHBITMAP = (pGdipCreateBitmapFromHBITMAP)GetProcAddress(hModuleThread, "GdipCreateBitmapFromHBITMAP");
    if(lGdipCreateBitmapFromHBITMAP == NULL)
    {
        // error
        return 0;
    }

    // load GdipSaveImageToFile
    lGdipSaveImageToFile = (pGdipSaveImageToFile)GetProcAddress(hModuleThread, "GdipSaveImageToFile");
    if(lGdipSaveImageToFile == NULL)
    {
        // error
        return 0;
    }

        lGdipCreateBitmapFromHBITMAP(hBmp, NULL, &pBitmap);

       iRes = GetEncoderClsid(L"image/jpeg", &imageCLSID);
       if(iRes == -1)
    {
        // error
        return 0;
    }
    encoderParams.Count = 1;
    encoderParams.Parameter[0].NumberOfValues = 1;
    encoderParams.Parameter[0].Guid  = EncoderQuality;
    encoderParams.Parameter[0].Type  = EncoderParameterValueTypeLong;
    encoderParams.Parameter[0].Value = &uQuality;

    lGdipSaveImageToFile(pBitmap, lpszFilename, &imageCLSID, &encoderParams);


    return 1;
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of calling GdipSaveImageToFile, you should use GdipSaveImageToStream.  This will let you save the image into a stream directly, instead of writing it to a file.

See the [GDI image functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534041.aspx) for details.

In order to create an IStream in memory, you can use [CreateStreamOnHGlobal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa378980(VS.85).aspx).  This has the option of allowing the IStream to allocate its own memory, or to use a pre-allocated buffer.